# WPF Application stalls/freezes after first interaction, like button click

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, buttonclick, intellitrace

I'm currently experiencing a problem in WPF. The UI loads fine, but whenever the first user interaction is made, such as a button click, the application seems to stall, or example if I had two buttons that display a MessageBox, the first click will wait for a few seconds then show the MessageBox, but any subsequent interaction is instantaneous and responsive.

Has anyone else experienced this? And if so, is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you are showing the message box using the overload version with parameter `this` refrence, it won't allow you to do anything until you close the messagebox.

Comment: I guess that's because of DLL loading, since .NET loads only what is referenced, so when the first reference of any object occur, it may cause a delay. That's what happening ...

Comment: This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947118/wpf-slow-to-start-on-x64-in-net-framework-4-0

Comment: I think I've figured it out , it appears to only be slow when debugging. If I build in release and run the app from the release folder in the bin directory, the stall or delay doesn't occur. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: I have noticed the same behaviour, but only in 64-bit builds (or AnyCPU on 64-bit OS) during debugging. The debug builds run without delay if started from the `Bin\Debug` directory. The delay is only present when the program is run with F5 in the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Every time I called the first interaction from a `Button` or `ICommand` the UI would freeze for like half a second.

I tracked down the issue with the hint of the author to start application directly from the folder. This solved the issue, but I also wanted to know why this happens and thought about what the difference is between direct execution and debugging.

So I figured out that `IntelliTrace` caused the freeze, which was still enabled since I activated it once for debugging an ADO.NET application. After disabling, the UI Freeze is gone. To disable it go to Debug -> IntelliTrace -> Open IntelliTrace Settings -> untick "Enable IntelliTrace".

Comment: We are investigating this issue to see if it can be resolved for a future version of Visual Studio. In the meantime, you may wish to just disable 'Gesture' events instead of completely disabling IntelliTrace. To do that go to 'Tools->Options->IntelliTrace->IntelliTrace Events' and disable 'Gesture' collection.

Comment: Thank you for your response Colin. I followed your instructions and it now seems to work with IntelliTrace enabled. Maybe you should also post this as answer, since it is actual better than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting this performance issue. We have looked into it and tracked it down. We are looking into fixing this in a future release. Below are steps to work around this issue. Once the work around is applied there is no need to disable ‘Gesture’ events or IntelliTrace.

1. Open up a cmd window under Admin account
2. cd /d "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64"
3. %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install /NoDependencies /ExeConfig:.\msvsmon.exe Microsoft.VisualStudio.vil.host.dll

If you are using a VM you might want to first save a snapshot before applying the work around. Let us know if you run into any other issues. Thanks.

Azeem Khan