# Basic WPF application take 10s to open (.NET 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ngen

Here is the situation:
I just build a basic WPF application with a simple grid with a `<LabeL>` that display Hello Word!

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestShell.NoCaliburn.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Hello World!</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

On my machine I have installed `.Net 4.5` and the application show up **under a second**. But on my collegue machine the application show up after **≈10s**.

- I've tried to repair .Net framework on my collegue machine
- Run this [Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947118/wpf-slow-to-start-on-x64-in-net-framework-4-0) (NGEN update)
- Compile the application under different .NET version
- Compile the application in 32 and 64 bits.

**NOTE**
This behavior happen only with WPF

What I'm missing ?

Comment: Are the specs of the machines the same? Are any other programs running?

Comment: Is there a virus scanner on the other machine that's not on yours?

Comment: SSD drive, network drive,...

Comment: We are both running on System Endpoint Protection

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh508836.aspx

Comment: Is he running a `Release` version or a `Debug` version with debug symbols?  Could add to the loading time.  Not to mention the spec differences.  At the same time, even with the same specs, the two machines are unlikely to be the same in performance.

Comment: We are running the same debug version

Comment: @Cedric, are VMs involved in any way? Could it be that the other machine is running on a starving host?

Comment: And when your colleague starts it the second time?

Comment: @Cedric Use a StopWatch to compute the time taken in code and note the exact difference. There could be many reasons but the first step is to measure.

Comment: @Henk Holterman ColdStart and WarmStart are getting the same result

Comment: There are way too many factors involved here, from CPU, HD to Load and usage patterns (is the Fx already loaded?). Only you can list the differences, and maybe try on a third PC.

Comment: @kanchirk the application is pretty basic I just added a label inside the VisualStudio WPF template

Comment: @Cedric Still I would suggest to measure it using a stopwatch class and run it multiple times on your machine and then on the other machine and check the results. You might have stumbled upon something interesting if not the regular ones mentioned by other SO experts.

Comment: @kanchirk I already add a Logger into a different application and the time is spent outside my Code

Comment: @Cedric Glad to hear. What about a console app? is it only the WPF app?

Comment: Yup  the behavior happen only with WPF

Comment: Different graphics cards?

Comment: Same graphic cards ...

Comment: If the second (slow) machine has a Visual Studio installation, you could run the performance profiler and inspect which methods cause this. It might give you a hint what could be wrong (e.g. WPF font cache or something).

Comment: I had such issues with buggy NVidia Graphics drivers. See my post how I profiled the issue and found the root cause: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/04/30/156156.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I experienced this issue

my wpf apps usually :

1- run faster on 32bit systems than 64bit systems

2- if directx is installed it will affect the application as the wpf is running based on directx and the version of directx is important also:

- directx version 7 or greater : No graphics hardware acceleration
- directx version 7 or greater and lesser than version 9.0 :  Rendering Tier 1 Partial graphics hardware acceleration
- directx version 9 or greater : Most graphics features use graphics hardware acceleration.

so most recent version always is better for your wpf app

use .net version 4 or later, for better clearer text

also check if the graphic card driver is installed and it's version is the latest release

and many more... but these infos are enough for your situation

good luck