# WPF 32 bit vs 64 bit CPU Usage

Tags: wpf, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32 bit WPF Application which runs fine. However, if I change it to 64 bit and run it, within a few seconds it starts to take up 25% of the CPU and stays that way. I would appreciate any pointers as to how to investigate and resolve this issue. Has anyone faced the same problem? Please comment.

The application is rather large and complex. It uses several third party dlls including Telerik controls and connections to ActiveMQ. The app used to work fine in the previous release in 64-bit mode. No third party dlls have been updated since the previous release. The target framework is .net 4.5

Thanks,
Bhanu

Comment: Does it happen with a blank empty WPF application, too? It should not. Out commenting your code might help to track the issue.

Comment: Is your .net framework version 4.0 ? see if the solution in this post help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947118/wpf-slow-to-start-on-x64-in-net-framework-4-0

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: would something like ANTS Performance Profiler be useful?  (I have no affiliation w/ that company but I have used their products and it helped me out quite a bit)

Comment: I am willing to try out the ANTS profiler if it is available on a trial basis. Can you please tell me what exactly I should be looking for in the profiler?

Comment: also, do you have any idea why the software would be working well in 32 bit mode and not in 64 bit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the framework to at least version 4.5.2.  I guess your rendering thread takes 1 cpu core. Use process explorer to view the threads usage.  (wpfgfx is your rendering thread)

Also update your graphics driver.

Comment: Upgrading the framework didn't solve the problem. I'm thinking it's a memory leak. It'll take me a few days to investigate with a profiler. I'll post back here when I find out. Thanks.